# JMSSerializer exclusion on self referencing group

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm having some trouble serializing self referencing properties with JMSSerializerBundle.

I want all properties but id included on the parent, but only id included on the child.

Entity:

```
class Member
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups("Member")
     */
    private $enrollIp;

    /**
     * @var Member
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups("Member")
     */
    private $originalEnroller;
```

Desired output:

```
{"enroll_ip":3232235521,"original_enroller":{"id":12345}}
```

Is there any way to do this?